# "toDate is not a function" when reading Timestamp property from Firestore (v7.1.0)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Despite there being numerous other (older) reports of this issue, none seem to match my circumstances.

I am writing a JSON object to Firestore with code (broadly) like this:

```js
const {Firestore, FieldValue} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const db = new Firestore();

const ref = db.collection('mycoll');
const queryRef = ref.where('someprop', '==', someval); // assume someval is defined
const obj = await queryRef.get();

obj.dateUpdated = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

await db.collection('mycoll').doc(obj.id).update(obj);
```

Later, I load the document again as a collection...

```js
const objects = [];
const snapshot = await db.collection('mycoll').get()
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  objects.push({
    id:  doc.id,
    data: doc.data()
  });
});
```

*Edit: The results from this query are sent over HTTP to the client (browser) to be parsed as plain JSON. See edit note below*

Looping through this objects collection, I'm trying to get the dateUpdated property

```js
for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  let obj = objects[i];
  console.log(obj.data.dateUpdated.toDate()); // <== Error thrown here
}
```

I get the error `TypeError: obj.data.dateUpdated.toDate is not a function`

If I just `console.log` the `dateUpdated` property

```
{
  "_seconds": 1698460669,
  "_nanoseconds": 951000000
}
```

It *seems* to be a `Timestamp`, but none of the timestamp operations work.

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

This post was misleading (or missing info). The last two snippets were executed on the client (browser) so the results of the query were simply sent over the wire as plan JSON objects. The failure to deserialize these as `Timestamp` objects is likely not a bug, but perhaps a feature request. I'm not sure how to use `Timestamp`s if the goal is to transmit plain JSON over the wire, and a plain javascript `Date` object gets serialized to a `Timestamp` when written, so it seems the only choice is to store raw epoch seconds/milliseconds as a `long`.

Comment: Hey Jason 
I asked around and this is not the expected behavior, but the engineers also can't reproduce what you get. The example also seems to be missing pieces, as you're setting `dateUpdated` on a `querySnapshot` and then passing that to `update(obj)`, which I think would raise an exception. --- Can you attach a debugger, and see what properties you get on `obj.data.dateUpdated` (or maybe even ` doc.data().dateUpdated`) have? We're wondering if there is some object cloning going on somewhere.

Comment: Hi Frank :)

Yeah I may have screwed up my sample in this post (it was a sanitized version of the real thing). I've since moved away from using a date and I'm just recording an epoch time as a long, but I can say that the first half (of my post) is largely irrelevant. When viewing the data (via cloud console) I saw the "dateUpdated" property, rendered in the console as a date, and the console.log seemed to render what looked like a date, but accessing the property didn't work. All other properties of the document are there as expected. If I have time I will see if I can repro

Comment: OK.. I know what happened. I confused the server side object with the (serialized & deserialized) client-side version. I'm returning the object over an API, so the remainder of the JSON transports fine, but presumably the Timestamp type does not deserialize on the client. So my code sample is wrong (well.. unclear about the last part being on the client). I will (vote to?) close this question, but separately I'd love to know how to get dates all the way back to the client

Comment: If you're not getting the date on the client, I wouldn't close the question - just edit it to clarify the code sample, including making it clear what runs on the client and what runs on the server. Unless you think it was PEBKAC of course, but that doesn't seem to be the case. --- For a minimal repro it really helps to start from scratch with just a few lines of code. Yes, annoying - I know. But also the best way to ensure we're all looking at the same, complete repro.

Comment: I don't think it's expected that a Timestamp would deserialize on the client from a raw REST API. It's just JSON over the wire. This is not the Firestore client library reading the result, it's just plain JS. So perhaps it's not a "bug" as much as a feature request. If i want to transmit documents over the wire to clients without the client having a dependency on Firestore, I can't use Timestamps because there's no easy way to deserialize them on the client. Unless you're saying this *should* work?

Comment: So your client is reading from Firestore through REST/gRPC directly? In that case, I expect that you indeed have to write your own deserializer for the timestamps - as they're not a native JavaScript/JSON type. We *could* write them as regular ms-since-the-epoch timestamps, but that'd be a lossy transformation - so lead to all kinds of problems when the client writes the value back.

Comment: Yes, just plain old JS objects over the wire. I didn't want to build a deserializer because the structure of the payload seemed to be "private" and felt it might be brittle to depend on, so opted to just store epoch time as a long. I will say that it's a little counter-intuititive that a JS `Date` object is serialized to a Firestore `Timestamp` on the way in, but is not easily "deserializable" to a `Date` on the way out. Using a long is "fine", but it does make debugging a little annoying as looking at the raw data in the console is less useful. I guess I could serialize to a String.. but ew.

Comment: "[I] opted to just store epoch time as a long" I do this all the time too. :-/

On serializing `Date`: while a `Date` object exists in JavaScript, it is not a known type in JSON. That's why Realtime Database never supported it. I'm not sure if the same logic applied to Firestore, but... it could be. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
// *1000 is to convert seconds to milliseconds as Date() requires milliseconds
// new Date() accepts milliseconds
// By default, Firestore returns the timestamp as an object with seconds and nanoseconds properties.

const date = new Date(dataUpdated._seconds * 1000);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: That looks like it would work, but I super don't like the idea of depending on an internal implementation like that. The underscore typically indicates "private" variables, and it's possible this may change (though also probably unlikely). This also doesn't explain why the documented behavior doesn't work, and if it's because I'm doing something wrong, I would prefer to fix it

Comment: Yes, fair enough. Thank you for sharing your thoughts, this encourages me to look into the documentation itself. Thank you again.